# MVVMCross with Xamarin.Forms and MasterDetail

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use a Xamarin.Forms master detail navigation with Mvvmcross.

App.cs

```
public partial class App : MvxFormsApp
{
    public App()
        : base()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        DependencyService.Register<AppContext>();
        InitializeComponent();
        // MainPage = new MasterDetail(); doing this would raise an InvalidCastException
    }

    protected override void OnParentSet()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        // Handle when your app starts
        // Initiate Navigation and navigate to the splashscreen
    }
...
```

App.Xaml:

```
<core:MvxFormsApp
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Stago.Mhp.Instr.Pocm.Core.Controls;assembly=Stago.Mhp.Instr.Pocm.Core"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Stago.Mhp.Instr.Pocm.Core.Converters;assembly=Stago.Mhp.Instr.Pocm.Core"
xmlns:forms9Patch="clr-namespace:Forms9Patch;assembly=Forms9Patch"
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms.Presenter.Core"
x:Class="Stago.Mhp.Instr.Pocm.Core.App">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <Color x:Key="BlackC90">#414142</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BlackC50">#939598</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BlackC05">#F1F1F2</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Black.20">#33000000</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Blue">#008DA8</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Red">#EE3524</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Orange">#F6A01A</Color>
        <Color x:Key="White">#F8F8F8</Color>
...
```

MvxFormsApplicationActivity.cs (Droid side)

```
[Activity(Label = "MvxFormsApplicationActivity", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
public class MvxFormsApplicationActivity : FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        var mvxFormsApp = new App();
        mvxFormsApp.MainPage = new MasterDetail();
        LoadApplication(mvxFormsApp);

        var presenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsDroidPagePresenter;
        presenter.MvxFormsApp = mvxFormsApp;

        Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>().Start();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the ResourceDictionary is not taken into account, and my app is unstyled.

If I remove the mvvmcross integration and inherit directly from Application (both App.cs and App.Xaml of course), it's working.

**Edit** For those who followed this question from start: exception has been resolved by putting the main page assignement in the `MvxFormsApplicationActivity`.

Comment: Any information about what it is trying to cast from and to? And where exactly this happen. Also remember, to be able to find the question and relevant details in the future, relevant parts of the code should be included here.

Comment: yup, it's all in the gist. I have no further explanation in the exception. I tried to find Xamarin.Forms mdb files for debug, but no luck...

Comment: Problem is that the gist might disappear...

Comment: damn right, was just lazy :)

Comment: So the line it happens is at LoadApplication. Would be really nice with a more complete stack trace. Do you maybe have some kind of version mismatch? I.e. if the MvvmCross Forms stuff is built against one version, while you are using another.

Comment: I don't understand, if you use the Xamarin.Forms, why you change the code of Activity in Droid project?

Comment: ok, then where do you put your application Resources ?